# PHP getting value inside curly braces

Tags: php

I have this so far:

```php
$response = json_decode($response, true);
foreach ($response['result'] as $loc)
{
        echo "" . $loc['metadata'] ."\n";
};
```

This outputs:

```
{   
    "name":"Bob",
    "image":"test.png",
    "description":"Test",
    "edition":"1",
    "size":"50x50",
    "type":"G",
    "location":"900,0",
    "attributes":[
        {
            "trait_type":"Location",
            "value":"900,0"
        },
        {
            "trait_type":"Size",
            "value":"50x50"},
        {
            "trait_type":"Type",
            "value":"G"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I get the value of "location"?

EDIT:

```
foreach ($response['result'] as $loc) {
    foreach ($loc['metadata'] as $lo) {
        $lo = json_decode($lo, true);
        echo "" .$lo['location'] . "\n";
    };
    //echo "" . $loc['metadata'] ."\n";
};
```

Comment: Looks as though you need to JSON decode it again.  Sometimes a field in a JSON file may also be JSON encoded.

Comment: I edited the code shown above. However, this stiff doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

you need to json decode the inner JSONString which exists in `$loc['metadata']`

```
foreach ($response['result'] as $loc) {
    $meta = json_decode($loc['metadata']);
    echo $meta['location'] ."\n";
}
```